# Navigate to a page on button click

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button here.

```
<button type="button">@item.StepsToList steps to list</button>
```

I want the button to go to the page similar to my action below.

> /ManageSpaces/id/Overview

I'm trying to do this by putting this action link inside the button.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage Yoga Space and Calendar", "Overview", new {controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "Overview", id = item.YogaSpaceId })
```

How to make the action link above work inside the `button` tag?

Comment: You can use `@Html.ActionLink()` inside `<button>` tags, or just style the link to look like a button

Comment: I tried putting my actionlink inside my button but nothing happens when I click the button. <button type="button">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Yoga Space and Calendar", "Overview", new { controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "Overview", id = item.YogaSpaceId })</button>

Comment: I got it! I used bootstrap classes to style an action link. posted answer below

Comment: Works for me. But looks like the overload is not correct - `<button type="button">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Yoga Space and Calendar", "Overview", "ManageSpaces", new { id = item.YogaSpaceId }, null)</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Buttons aren't for navigation. That's what hyperlinks are for. Putting a non-anchor `<a>` inside of a `<button>` isn't valid, either. If your focus is on the **look** of a button, your choices are to

- use a button. Capture the click event and navigate the page using window.location, or
- use a hyperlink. Add a CSS framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation, and apply one of their button styles.

Assuming you're familiar with jQuery at all, something like this works for the former point:

```
<button class="link-button" data-url="/some/url">I navigate somewhere</button>

<script>
    $('.link-button').on('click', function(e) {
        window.location = $(this).data('url');
    });
</script>
```

For the latter point, Bootstrap and Foundation both have dedicated styles for making just about anything look like a "button":

#### [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

```
<a href="/some/url" class="btn btn-default">I navigate somewhere</a>
```

#### [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html)

```
<a href="#" class="button">I navigate somewhere</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to simply navigate to a new page? If so you should use an `Html.ActionLink` by itself instead of a `<button>` - that's what they're for. You can style the resulting `<a>` element to look like a button. If you want to post a form to a new action method, you should specify that in your call to `Html.BeginForm`, then the button will automatically submit to that action when clicked.

Comment: when I click on the button I want to navigate to /ManageSpaces/id/Overview

Comment: Then use `Html.ActionLink` and style it like a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage Yoga Space and Calendar", "Overview", new { controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "Overview", id = item.YogaSpaceId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default " })
```