# redirect multiple submit button to different page

Tags: php, html, forms

i made a post form in html, but i have multiple choices so once the user clicks one of the choices then it will redirect them to the page
each choice have a different choice
can you all advice how can i achieve that?
im coding in PHP.

```
      echo "<form action='home.php' method='post'>";
      echo "<input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Yes'>";
      echo "<input type='submit'  name='submit' value='No'>"; 
      // If no i want this button to redirect to another page instead of home.php
      echo "</form>";
```

I appreciate any help. I know this is very basic T_T

Comment: do you need Yes/No value or any other values to be passed to the target page upon submit?

Comment: can you show us the code for button submission.

Comment: @Oops, there is no such code. buttons itself are `type='submit'` so they are submitting the form actually.

Comment: This will done with little javascript

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with same name in form (i.e. have those named `submit1` and `submit2`).

Comment: @mitkosoft I asked,so that can check the form submission,.. if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // do something }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigate to a page on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662692/navigate-to-a-page-on-button-click)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Comment: "// If no i want this button to redirect to another page instead of home.php" Just make two anchor links instead of form. Each link should be href-ed with appropriate landing page.

Answer (score 3):

First of all change the name of submit fields. In your case both are same. *I am giving it as yes and no.*

```
  echo "<input type='submit'  name='yes' value='Yes'>";
  echo "<input type='submit'  name='no' value='No'>";
```

You can redirect to a page by using **header functions in php**. For this check which button is submitted. If you clicked on yes/no then redirect to your desired page. You can check it by

```
 if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
    header("Location: home.php") // redirect to your desired page
 }

 if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
    header("Location: anotherPage.php") // redirect to your desired page
 }
```

Comment: @hellopanda :let me know whether you got it or not

Comment: i used formaction instead as its neater

Answer (score 2):

You can use `formaction` attribute within your submit buttons:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" formaction="home.php" value="No">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" formaction="otherPage.php" value="Yes">
</form>
```

This will submit the form to the desired page, together with any other parameters in your form (if any).